# couldn't access history of react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

The history is undefined, while trying to call `this.props.history.push("/home")`.

**Code:**

***Index.js***

```
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
  <HashRouter>
    <App location />
  </HashRouter>
);
```

***App.js***

```
export class App extends React.Component {
  handleClick = () => {
    this.props.history.push("/home");
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <button onClick={() => this.handleClick()}>Click to Nav</button>
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

React-Router: v5.2.0

CodeSandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-wing-ju5ou9?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `App` component needs to be either rendered by a `Route` component so it can be passed [route props](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-props) so there's a defined `history` prop, ***or*** decorate and export `App` with the [withRouter](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter) Higher Order Component.

App

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

class App extends React.Component {
  handleClick = () => {
    this.props.history.push("/home");
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <button onClick={() => this.handleClick()}>Click to Nav</button>
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(App);
```

[image: Edit couldnt-access-history-of-react-router]

Alternatively you could convert `App` to a React function component and import and use the `useHistory` hook instead.

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

const App = () => {
  const history = useHistory();

  const handleClick = () => {
    history.push("/home");
  };

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <button onClick={handleClick}>Click to Nav</button>
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

[image: Edit couldnt-access-history-of-react-router (forked)]

I see also that you are using `react@18` and `react-router-dom@5.2.0` ***and*** had removed the `React.StrictMode` component in your `index.js` file. There was an issue introduced by `react@18` that broke RRDv5 routing (*described [here](https:///a/71833424/8690857)*) that was resolved in `react-router-dom@5.3.3` so I suggest you upgrade to the latest v5 version.

```
npm i -s react-router-dom @5
```

index.js

```
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import { HashRouter } from "react-router-dom";

import App from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <HashRouter>
      <App />
    </HashRouter>
  </StrictMode>
);
```